# How to display SQL query of a CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

I would like to display in the `Log.d` the current SQL query being generated by a `CursorLoader` in the `onCreateLoader` method such as:

```
                        return new CursorLoader(
                            getActivity(),          // Parent activity context
                            WifiEntry.CONTENT_URI,  // Provider content URI to query
                            projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                            null,                   // No selection clause
                            null,                   // No selection arguments
                            WifiEntry.COLUMN_WIFI_NAME + " ASC");
```

I have looked at the Android docs, and in here, but no success. It is useful to debugging purposes to be able to visualize the SQL string.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**. I am adding the ContentProvider query method, anybody can answer how to display in the Log the resulting SQL query?
Thanks.

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    // Get readable database
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    // This cursor will hold the result of the query
    Cursor cursor;

    // Figure out if the URI matcher can match the URI to a specific code
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match)
    {
        case WIFIS:
            // For the WIFIS code, query the wifi table directly with the given
            // projection, selection, selection arguments, and sort order. The cursor
            // could contain multiple rows of the pets table.
            cursor = database.query(WifiEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case WIFI_ID:
            // For the WIFI_ID code, extract out the ID from the URI.
            // the selection will be "_id=?"
            selection = WifiEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };
            cursor = database.query(WifiEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query, unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    // Return the cursor
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: then see `ContentProvider#query` method, that method is indirectly called by a `CursorLoader`

Comment: ok but how.. I tried query.toString.. but it displays just the path, how do you display the actual SQL query?

Comment: what is `WifiEntry` ? is it your custom `ContentProvider` ? if so, take a look on its `query` method

Comment: public static class WifiEntry implements BaseColumns . In it it is defined the contract for the DB. The URIs, content authorities, db columns, etc. Content provider is defined in another class, where it overrides its methods, such as query.  There are things like cursor = database.query(WifiEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null, null, sortOrder);

Comment: so use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` in that `"another class, where it overrides its methods, such as query"` - use method `buildQueryString()` / `buildQuery()`